# Flutter remove left space in image slider

Tags: image, flutter, slider, carousel

[Remove the left space ..in this i use container with padding 0  & margin 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlCp4.png)

Comment: Is there any padding given inside your `ListView`? Can you show your code

Comment: in these i am not use listview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListView, you have to modify the padding attribute, you can use 'padding: EdgeInsetsGeometry.zero' to remove the padding from the list